How can I take advantage of useAxios composable when I don't know in advance which data to pass to it?
I'm trying to create a TS service by leveraging composables and by using DummyJSON as BE. This is what I did, step by step.
Set axios base URL
// src/axios/index.ts

import axios from 'axios'

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://dummyjson.com'

Import axios/index.ts
// main.ts

import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './axios'

const app = createApp(App)

app.mount('#app')

Create todo.service.ts
// src/composables/services/todo.service.ts

import { useAxios } from '@vueuse/integrations/useAxios'

const BASE_URL = '/todos'

// Keeping composables naming convention
const useTodoService = {
  getAll: () => {
    return useAxios(`${BASE_URL}`) // GET by default
  }
}

Test it
// src/views/TestView.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import useTodoService from '@/composables/services/todo.service'

const { data, isLoading } = useTodoService.getAll()
</script>

<template>
  <div>Loading: {{ isLoading }}</div>
  <div>First todo: {{ data?.todos[0] }}</div>
</template>

It works as it should, but...what if I want to actually call the API after pressing a button? It gets just a tiny bit more cumbersome.
Update todo.service.ts
const useTodoService = {
  getAll: () => {
    return useAxios(
      `${BASE_URL}`,
      {}, // GET by default
      { immediate: false }
    )
  }
}

Test it (again)
// src/views/TestView.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import useTodoService from '@/composables/services/todo.service'

const { data, isLoading, execute } = useTodoService.getAll()
</script>

<template>
  <div>Loading: {{ isLoading }}</div>
  <div>First todo: {{ data?.todos[0] }}</div>
  <div><button @click="execute">Fire!</button></div>
</template>

And again, it works as it should. But what if the API needs data? What if I need to do something on that data before sending them?
First of all, I don't want other devs to directly touch axios data object (or at least I think so...). I want some kind of abstraction layer.
Second of all, I don't want to repeat the data refinement code each time before calling the API.
Things start getting a little messy.
Update todo.service.ts
const useTodoService = {
  getAll: () => {
    // Same code as before
  },
  add: () => {
    const useAxiosObj = useAxios(
      `${BASE_URL}/add`,
      { method: 'POST' },
      { immediate: false }
    )

    // Creating an execute function which is going to override the one provided by useAxios
    const execute = (title: string) => {
      // Fency refinement here

      // Calling useAxios execute method
      return useAxiosObj.execute({ data: { todo: title, completed: false, userId: 5 } })
    }

    return { ...useAxiosObj, execute }
  }
}

Test it (fingers crossed)
// src/views/TestView.vue

<script setup lang="ts">
import useTodoService from '@/composables/services/todo.service'

const { data, isLoading, execute } = useTodoService.add()

function onClick() {
  execute('Lorem ipsum...')
}
</script>

<template>
  <div>Loading: {{ isLoading }}</div>
  <div>Added todo: {{ data }}</div>
  <div><button @click="onClick">Fire!</button></div>
</template>

It works, but:

It's out of standard. People used to useAxios expect a different execute function.
Following IDE warning is shown: Expected a non-Promise value to be spreaded in an object.

As you saw, I had to write a lot of code to add some kind of abstraction and to have only one place for the data refinement code. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something, how can I fix/improve it?

A composable is supposed to called immediately in setup, so in order for it to be conveniently used, it can be expected to be provided with all data that is necessary for it to work, i.e. support refs for data that may change with time.
As it can be seen in useAxios implementation, it doesn't specifically support reactive values in initial configuration, so providing data to execute is the expected way to use it.

Expected a non-Promise value to be spreaded in an object

This is linter error that can be effectively ignored in this case because useAxios returns promise-like object instead of Promise. This makes its current TypeScript type incorrect and identifies the problem with the service, as ...useAxiosObj would be incorrect if the implementation were changed. But immediate: false suggests that a promise isn't intended to be used, it's safe to ignore the linter rule for this use. And considering that mutating useAxiosObj doesn't cause to problems, a more correct way to return extended promise object regardless of useAxios implementation would be:
return Object.assign(useAxiosObj, { execute });


People used to useAxios expect a different execute function

It's unlikely this is important as the service doesn't declare the compatibility with it, not to mention that VueUse's useAxios isn't a standard. execute could be named differently if this is an issue. But the problem with the service is that it exposes too much of the underlying API  without keeping execute promise, which can useful for correct control flow.
If the service is first-party, and the possible uses are known, the result could be reduced to the values that are actually used, this also eliminates the problem with a destructured promise.
A possible enhancement is to rely on reactive data for side effects instead of explicit execute calls:
  add: (titleRef?: Ref<string>) => {
    const { data, error, isLoading, execute } = useAxios(..., { immediate: false })

    if (titleRef) {
      watchEffect(() => {
        if (titleRef.value != null)
          query(titleRef.value);
      });
    }

    function query(title) {
        ...
        const promise = execute({ data: ... });
        return promise;
    }

    return { data, error, isLoading, query }
  }


I have a some questions:

If a composable should be called immediately, how can people effectively use useAxios if they don't know in advance which data to pass to it? That's why it's possible to pass data to execute function. Am I wrong?
If I change execute function name to something else, devs can access the original function provided by useAxios. I lose the abstraction.
I edited the code, now the execute Promise is kept.



I'm returning the whole useAxios object to avoid destructuring and returning the same things over and over again.
I don't really like passing refs. The idea was to create a reactive service-like thing. Same as using plain old Axios with no composables.



It could have api I suggested for "add" (titleRef), so initial request data could be composed of refs that may not have assigned values at the time when the composable is called 2. You're probably overthinking it, if your composable suits the intended usage, there's no need to expose the underlying useAxios, otherwise it can be changed to suit your and other devs' needs 5. It's up to you, this is one of the ways to use a composable. If you don't need to deeply rely on reactivity, there could be even no need for useAxios, axios() itself is straightforward to use with vue, depends on the case


Tbh my idea was to take advantage of useAxios data, isLoading and error refs. That's why I thought it was a good idea to create a thing (a service?) like this

I see. I don't benefit from this kind of composables much, it's a matter of style, e.g. errors can be handled globally in axios interceptor. Anyway it's ok to do it the way you're doing it now, but to make it more foolproof it's better to expose as least as you really need. E.g. currently overexposing of underlying useAxios allows for this kind of accidental use let { data } = await useTodoService.getAll(), which could lead to problems (getAll() is pending promise that never resolves because of immediate:false). See the update in the answer regarding linter error caused by this promise
